# Getting "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it" error

Tags: jquery, window

I have opened a window from another page. On button click, I want to close this window. However, the browser is complaining that "Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it".

I tried:

```
window.open('', '_parent', '');
window.close();
```

but its not working. 
Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [window.close() doesn't work - Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937212/window-close-doesnt-work-scripts-may-close-only-the-windows-that-were-opene)

Answer (score 0):

The below code worked for me

```
window.open('location of current page', '_self', '');
window.close();
```