# close opened tab using jquery on close button

Tags: jquery

this is my code working fine on localhost but not working on live donn't why

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function closeWindow() { 
window.open('','_parent',''); 
window.close(); 
} 
</script>
<a href="javascript:closeWindow();">Close Tab</a>
```

Tried this also

```
<script>
  function Exit() {
     var x=confirm('Are You sure want to Close Tab');
     if(x) window.close();
   }
</script>

<button name='closeIt' onClick="Exit()" >CLICK </Button>
```

please help

Comment: what error you are getting in console  ? ?

Comment: Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it. m getting this error @punit please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var win = window.open("about:blank", "_self");
win.close();
```

Comment: on click it display about:blank not closing the tab

Comment: and  var win = window.open("", "_self"); display error
 Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

Comment: I searched for many pages of the web through of the Google and here on the Stack Overflow, but nothing suggested resolved my problem.

After many attempts and "kicks" I changed my way of to test that controller. Then I have discovered that the problem occurs always which I reopened the page through of the Ctrl + Shift + T shortcut in Chrome. So the page was run, but without a parent window reference, and because this can't be closed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937212/window-close-doesnt-work-scripts-may-close-only-the-windows-that-were-opene

Comment: directly you cannot close the window sry.

Answer (score 0):

Simple ask confirmation if it's true then continue to next action and if it's false nothing to do action it's stay the same page

```
function Exit(){
           var retVal = confirm("Do you want to continue ?");
           if( retVal == true ){
              document.write ("User wants to continue!");
              return true;
           }
           else{
              document.write ("User does not want to continue!");
              return false;
           }
        }
```

i hope it's work

Comment: There should be no "try" or "hope" about it. Either your code works or it doesn't. Please test it to be sure. Please explain what your code is doing so that it can be useful to people who want to learn.

Comment: Simple ask confirmation if it's true then continue to next action and if it's false nothing to do action it's stay the same page

Comment: Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it. it display this not not closing the tab

Comment: @SujalPatel great! Put that in the answer.

Comment: <a href="#" onclick="javascript:var win = window.open('', '_self');win.close();return false;">Close</a>
 i tried various solution nothing works on live
Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it. this displays on console

Comment: @SujalPatel please help