# Can close a TAB that was opened by user and not programatically for Chrome/FireFox/Safari?

Tags: javascript

https://content.screencast.com/users/rahul15.choudhary/folders/Jing/media/4371df19-c259-49a8-b0f2-9599bccebe48/2018-06-27_1929.png[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbpA8.png)

Can close a TAB that was opened by user and not programatically for Chrome/FireFox/Safari?

Comment: Browsers only allow to close tabs which are open pragmatically (Dynamic) by script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.close() doesn't work - Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937212/window-close-doesnt-work-scripts-may-close-only-the-windows-that-were-opene)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.close and self.close do not close the window in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)