# How to close the webpage on its own on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, windows

I have a page where a `<button>` is kept on which `onClick()` event fires and redirects the new page in new tab. Meanwhile I want the parent page to close itself as soon as the `<button>` is clicked with opening the new page in new tab. Its basically for some security feature for the website. How can this be done? 
Here is my `<button>`, let me know where can i correct myself.

`<button formtarget="_blank" type="submit" name="submit" onClick="javascript:window.open('quiz.php?unit_id=<?php echo $fnc->encode($unit_id) ; ?>');self.close();" value="submit" class="btn btn-info" style='margin-left: 35%;margin-bottom: 10px;' ><i class="glyphicon"></i> Start Quiz</button>`

Comment: If your script did not initiate opening the window (with something like window.open), then the script in that window is not allowed to close it. Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937212/window-close-doesnt-work-scripts-may-close-only-the-windows-that-were-opene

Comment: Wait clicking the button opens a *new tab* and you want to close the *old tab* at the same time. Unless I'm missing something, why not just open the URL in the same tab?

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for prompt reply. I appreciate. Yes, I want to close the current window on clickingthe button and opening the new window in new tab.

Comment: @Ansh But *why* a open a new tab and close the current one? Why not redirect within the same tab? You seem to be doing the same thing effectively. Without an explanation - this seems like it's unnecessary or an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @VLAZ Its an online quiz module and I dont want the user to get back on some other page while attempting the quiz.

Comment: @Ansh so it's an XY problem then. You should be able to clear the history of the back button. In addition, you can set the server to send no-cache headers and invalidate the previously sent ones. I'm not sure how myself but I've seen this technique used where you submit a page and upon going back you get a "page is outdated" message in some form, so it's doable. It's reasonably common, as well - I've seen it in a few places. There are probably other things you can do. But your question should be "how do I prevent users from going back". At the very least closing a page means it can be reopened

Answer (score 0):

you can close window by below function

```
function close(){
 setTimeout("window.close()", 500);
}
```

**But keep in mind that :** Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

Comment: Don't use strings within `setTimeout` - pass a function. A string calls `eval` which is unnecessary. Let's leave aside security aspects, at an even more basic level it's just bad from maintainability perspective. And let's take even the most basic version of that - syntax highlight won't work in your editor of choice. There are just more and more problems up the chain from there and passing a string doesn't address anything other than making the code slightly shorter as you (at best) omit typing `function() { }`

Answer (score 0):

The window close and open new tab

```
<script language="javascript">

function quitWindow(cmd) 
{      
    if(window.open("your_new_tab_page.htm")){
        if (cmd=='quit')    
        {
           open(location, '_self').close();    
        }   
    }
    return false;   
}

</script>

<input  type="submit" onclick="return quitWindow('quit');" value="Close This Window and open new Tab" />
```

If you use firefox, you should about:config by writing url bar and set

```
dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows = true
```

otherwise does not work firefox

Comment: Thanks , i tried this, but the current webpage does not closes. Can something else be done?

Comment: @Ansh If you use firefox, you should configure about:config by writing url bar and set

    dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows = true

otherwise does not work firefox

Comment: Thanks for this. But can you demonstrate me in above code?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work.

```
    <script>

    function openWindow( url )
    {
            window.open(url, '_blank');
            window.focus();
            window.close();
    }

    </script>
    <button onclick="javascript:openWindow(yourHref);return false;">Submit</button>
```

Comment: can you explain me this above mentioned answer? I mean `window.open(url, '_blank', "shilpijain" ,"modal=no");`, I couldnot get this part.

Comment: @Ansh window.open(URL, name, specs _(optional)_ , replace _(optional)_ ) 
refer - [w3s](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

features can also be added., 
window.open(url, windowName, [windowFeatures]);
refer - [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features)

Answer (score 0):

You cant close your webpage if the user clicked the link of your website from any other place other than your website, due to security reasons.

[image: Scripts can close sites that are opened by scripts only]