# How to close a window using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I tried to close a window using **window.close()** when user clicks on cancel button, but window not closing.I am getting the following message in console

```
scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.
```

Comment: You will have to come up with a way to open the window with javascript, then you can close it with javascript - this seems to work https://jeffclayton.wordpress.com/2015/02/13/javascript-window-close-method-that-still-works/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.close() doesn't work - Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937212/window-close-doesnt-work-scripts-may-close-only-the-windows-that-were-opene)

Answer (score 0):

this question has already been answered [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937212/window-close-doesnt-work-scripts-may-close-only-the-windows-that-were-opene)

This method `window.close()` is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the `window.open()` method.

> It's a security to prevent a website taking control of your browser and closing windows.

You can try this. As it has been used here [Reference Link](https://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/MSIE7Bugs/ClosingWindowsNotOpenedByJS.html)

```js
function CloseWithWindowOpenTrick()
{
    var objWindow = window.open(location.href, "_self");
    objWindow.close();
}
```

Comment: Actually, it is a duplicate from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome).

Comment: can try this also `open(location, '_self').close();`   [See Its also answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)