# Why is Javascript not working on page opened by redirect?

Tags: javascript, c#, redirect, model-view-controller

I have a problem where a page that is opened as a result of a redirect call does not execute the javascript function.
This page is simply a message to indicate that an OAuth2 user session has started so I want it to close right away.  It is opened by the redirect initiated by the OAuth server after processing the access_token request.

If I access this page in testing it works fine:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://localhost:44302/Home/SessionOpen");
```

The page loads, closes in 2 seconds.

If it is opened via the redirect it never closes...

The dead simple page:

```
<body  onload="closeit();">
    <div style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
        <h3>Session has started.</h3>
        <h4>If this window does not close automatically you may close it manually.</h4>

        <script type='text/javascript'>

            function closeit(){

                setTimeout(function() {
                 window.close();
               }, 2000);
            };

        </script>
    </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: browsers locked down close to prevent misuse. If you did not make the window with window.open or with the window changed domains, you most likely can not close it. I am sure there is an error/warning in the console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [window.close() doesn't work - Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937212/window-close-doesnt-work-scripts-may-close-only-the-windows-that-were-opene)

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried taking the javascript snippet out of the body ?
I think that could be the solution

Comment: Not going to make any difference

Comment: So true, my bad. The problem is:
"Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them." Update: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937212/window-close-doesnt-work-scripts-may-close-only-the-windows-that-were-opene

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).